Poisson process without the indepedent increments?
From Wikipedia:
A counting process is a homogeneous Poisson counting process with rate $\lambda > 0$ if it has the following three properties:

$N ( 0 ) = 0$;
has independent increments;
the number of events (or points) in any interval of length $t$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\mathit λ t$.

I have a problem regarding the independent increments property: I can't find a counterexample of a stochastic process (other than a Poisson process) which violates the independent increments assumption, but keeps the other two. Is there a way to construct such a counterexample?

Hi: Any stochastic process that ihas autocorrelation at more than one lag, won't have independent increments that are of length one. Take an AR(2) where the increments are of length $t=1$. This process doesn't have independent increments because the current value is dependent on data that is two lags previous. As far as stochastc processes that have autocorrelation at more than lag, I'm not sure how many there are but there must be quite a few ?

A result of A. Renyi from 1967 say that if
$$
P[N(A)=0]=e^{-\lambda|A|},\qquad\qquad (*)
$$
whenever $A$ is a finite union of intervals, then $N$ is a Poisson process.
(Here $N(A)$ is the number of points that the counting process places in $A$, and $|A|$ is the total length of $A$.) Of course if $N(A)$ has the Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda|A|$ then ($*$) holds. So if you strengthen your hypothesis to include finite unions of intervals (not just intervals) then the independence hypothesis can be omitted.
Moran  provided an example of what can go wrong  when the Poisson distribution property only holds for intervals:  "A non-Markovian quasi-Poisson process", Stud. Sci. Math. Hung. 2 (1967) 425-429.
Kingman's book Poisson Processes has a nice discussion of the matter.
